# ContentQuery filtering by URL

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have list where i have som news with title, date, department.
I want to make a filter so that list is showing the news from the Januar 2016, or April 2016 for that department.

I can filter the contentquery so that shows me just that department by URL/search?department=Economy but now i want the users to allow them to se news just for January - how should this filter be ? any ideas?

I have createddate in list - so the query should be like seard?date=01-01-2016 and date 30-01-2016 & Department=economy